# raphael icons hover

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, raphael

I have the following basic code, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLZKc/

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="chat"><span>Chat</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="heart"><span>Heart</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="documentation"><span>Documentation</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this javascript:

```js
var bubble = "M16,5.333c-7.732,0-14,4.701-14,10.5c0,1.982,0.741,3.833,2.016,5.414L2,25.667l5.613-1.441c2.339,1.317,5.237,2.107,8.387,2.107c7.732,0,14-4.701,14-10.5C30,10.034,23.732,5.333,16,5.333z", 
    heart = "M24.132,7.971c-2.203-2.205-5.916-2.098-8.25,0.235L15.5,8.588l-0.382-0.382c-2.334-2.333-6.047-2.44-8.25-0.235c-2.204,2.203-2.098,5.916,0.235,8.249l8.396,8.396l8.396-8.396C26.229,13.887,26.336,10.174,24.132,7.971z", 
    documentation = "M26.679,7.858c-0.176-0.138-0.404-0.17-0.606-0.083l-9.66,4.183c-0.42,0.183-0.946,0.271-1.486,0.271c-0.753,0.002-1.532-0.173-2.075-0.412c-0.194-0.083-0.356-0.176-0.471-0.259c0.042-0.021,0.09-0.042,0.146-0.064l8.786-3.804l1.31,0.561V6.612c0-0.244-0.106-0.475-0.283-0.612c-0.176-0.138-0.406-0.17-0.605-0.083l-9.66,4.183c-0.298,0.121-0.554,0.268-0.771,0.483c-0.213,0.208-0.397,0.552-0.394,0.934c0,0.01,0.003,0.027,0.003,0.027v14.73c0,0.006-0.002,0.012-0.002,0.019c0,0.005,0.002,0.007,0.002,0.012v0.015h0.002c0.021,0.515,0.28,0.843,0.528,1.075c0.781,0.688,2.091,1.073,3.484,1.093c0.66,0,1.33-0.1,1.951-0.366l9.662-4.184c0.255-0.109,0.422-0.383,0.422-0.692V8.471C26.961,8.227,26.855,7.996,26.679,7.858zM20.553,5.058c-0.017-0.221-0.108-0.429-0.271-0.556c-0.176-0.138-0.404-0.17-0.606-0.083l-9.66,4.183C9.596,8.784,9.069,8.873,8.53,8.873C7.777,8.874,6.998,8.699,6.455,8.46C6.262,8.378,6.099,8.285,5.984,8.202C6.026,8.181,6.075,8.16,6.13,8.138l8.787-3.804l1.309,0.561V3.256c0-0.244-0.106-0.475-0.283-0.612c-0.176-0.138-0.407-0.17-0.606-0.083l-9.66,4.183C5.379,6.864,5.124,7.011,4.907,7.227C4.693,7.435,4.51,7.779,4.513,8.161c0,0.011,0.003,0.027,0.003,0.027v14.73c0,0.006-0.001,0.013-0.001,0.019c0,0.005,0.001,0.007,0.001,0.012v0.016h0.002c0.021,0.515,0.28,0.843,0.528,1.075c0.781,0.688,2.091,1.072,3.485,1.092c0.376,0,0.754-0.045,1.126-0.122V11.544c-0.01-0.7,0.27-1.372,0.762-1.856c0.319-0.315,0.708-0.564,1.19-0.756L20.553,5.058z";

$('.chat').each(function(i) {
    chat = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40)
    chat.path(bubble).attr({
        "fill" : "#333"
    })
})

$('.heart').each(function(i) {
    paper = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40)
    paper.path(heart).attr({
        "fill" : "#333"
    })
})
$('.documentation').each(function(i) {
    paper = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40)
    paper.path(documentation).attr({
        "fill" : "#333"
    })
})
```

I am trying to attach a hover action on each icon, so that if the user hovers over a menu item, the icon changes color.

If I add a mouseover, like:

```js
$('.chat').each(function(i) {
    chat = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40);
    chat.path(bubble).attr({
        "fill" : "#333"
    })
    chat.mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            "fill" : "#fff"
        });
    });
})
```

I get an error, 'Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'mouseover' '

What will be the correct way to do this? Also can the code be simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. `mouseover` is being added to the Raphael paper (canvas). It should be added to the shape instead.
2. The code mixes Raphael shape references and jQuery element references. `$(this)` should be replaced with `this` in some cases to refer to the event's owner (the Raphael shape).
3. Assuming you're going for the opposite behavior on mouse out, Raphael's `hover` should be used to tie both handlers to the shape.

Let's recap these by a code snippet example:

```js
$('.chat').each(function(i) {
    chat = Raphael($(this)[0], 40, 40);
    var shape = chat.path(bubble).attr({
        "fill": "#333"
    });
    shape.hover(function() {
        this.attr({
            "fill": "#fff"
        });
    }, function() {
        this.attr({
            "fill": "#333"
        });
    });
})
```

You can refer to the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/fLZKc/1/) to further manipulate it.

Comment: oh i see, thank you for the explanation. in order to have the same functionality for all the .chat, .documentation and .heart how would you loop over these elements and attach the same hover functionality?